# What is this thing?

Tags: hardware

We just moved into a new office.  The previous tenants went out of business, and left behind anything they couldn't sell off in a hurry.

One of the objects left behind was this thing:

[image: Top]

[image: Front]

[image: Back]

It looks brand new, and kinda like the world's smallest blade.  It even has the all-purpose port thing on the back.

Anyone know what it is?

Comment: Do I see a hard drive AND a memory chip towards the back of it?

Comment: Could be a system board for phones or a multi-funtion copier/printer.  Do you have any higher resolution images? Any including a part number of manufacturer?

Comment: @DavidW Yes, boards like this usually boot their OS from the flash card (lower left pic #1) and use the hdd for writing.

Comment: it looks like a PRI card out of a nortel PBX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a voicemail server for a PBX system, possibly Nortel or NEC based on the form-factor. If you can get a clearer shot of the front panel that includes model numbers I could tell you better.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a [blade computer intended for use in a chassis switch](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&objectID=c02536759&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN). HP and several other manufacturers have similar modules that are essentially a computer on a blade.

However, a [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZive7ZiS7fVn5SgeIrFm6D_1-aNXid_1iBM9YGDq3OINVsH7vka2WySZAKHHU2Gnuwce3rRAdPZ8m7_1YTmp6PWmWTFQUj9qnOX58_1OMXNm7m1AbuZi-TfnmmtEsvh4R-a-hTA9--UKXgxg7vicNWPTC-UYTQl9JEcPtrxq9YV5vnpFW6fI9DdfFocWrLSBHv2el3K4kXfnBgmued6hjyjsY8M-NSRhsVzgoS3wwrxAfxoD8MK_1LXMezQ8-5BfPsw4nR5MvHo_1Ln16SdGmw0BxxJ7Fv1eykEHCo0pfJ1IJJAHWlnJVRsqId8wl9hAqOuWD8yWSjmKEAxbGpkqpbp9fqagFbVLbNcX1AyDbrEN8CE0dJLaLNvVfQN0ShHOblz-z8TRfX6RqXnSJ9D-rv_1ZgLKCwq0LXJgwL7QziB9WiHKiIMcfY0x_1T1uh40W50q-2Tlo1cnPZzbOQuC0AM4arbSxv4rZ8OBqupdQCdZkP11Cm-fQK_16xSGzLyZ9_1w-unSwl_1kJJNcTzB1XK6cFddJ9oow_1-vcxnf99XmvO9iDzPRB8FJrqCoPMXv9jPFgKUq9brwV_1REKadXPvW6SQa31KyWQVsNr8f2BvoSJZlu7y2Bzm031CxuHHEk0s9bIBa5blIdaswqqnXLna_1mrmxG6Wf8rchhp6fLaPbpV_104vMqKRKE_1vGJEmu1I4FdVwAnhMu_111Vbx9nkFxZ8A2hJ1Uv-A6nYx08cHzHrOsxVTZ98GOjRTrGcczR2WpG4a7oI4uZOLZOC0osSEMmzxdedSQGlEM81-5dEQ4hu5n2DgtFLf0L5tOUiWIz_1o0sdncqQU6SsY1-h3qSB0chPIEr0KRjTnH0rZxM-TZAWymWHswWS6qS87nda6zeiIvxCOwM1esGzyEUdFOaY2-P-W52cobrFlxurXkyp891z93rmJq7bJ6AHwRizTEFm20aXy-exTEl93JDvEe4VX-W--8FfHEMMvOS-02xQLUHz0ZtOIDIFxNmlodPhBc6z5oMHL_1Oc2I9_10Jx-nbCmaRzXtHkmc2mgTE98V4aphrkpzB8HUJEvIRggC-5qFnz98ogv2KQgPLSkz1LsdamkOYh2pl45dHF2NGK0E7IrFkAPfNxJIcuRS1DZ6I2CoFgWS7QuezGicdfevkKuMfDhB0UvI7E15u1QWDNlOKtX6_1WU1A5yhR8iGjvq2QJ8evXIYe2WWZfW8ILv5hSvQUJGYbmSWd4ydbzSZgLKj0cFEZvHuwN2npoBe06nEcEyCwB-E-3GToQ3dExd4tdNRJQ0kUOw1C336TOoRuaSQJfvMimDOi3DXvfGIJomQ5mLeVIU6nu4ffHl6nmSRYZa7eT0M9nAd9azsz6NLR3vDnjzngchEs8HAHt5fQ930SaZjgnZaiyT0EF8AZqHlyBEkp7hlbp5ise45bge2ocZGActcLUVIdVteLqJgxdKGyB0i4k&hl=en&tbo=d&authuser=0&biw=1431&bih=931&site=imghp&sa=X&ei=0xUVUYS6GaP6yQHu34CoAw&ved=0CFMQ9Q8) shows the HD as a basic SATA laptop drive. This is probably a module for a copier/multifunction printing device.